# Is variadic macro subsitution for every argument possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I read quite a few questions on SO about variadic macros now, but it doesn't seem like anyone answered the most simple question:

```
#define IDENTITY(x) x
#define IDENTITY_FOR_ALL(...) ???
```

Is there a way to make `IDENTITY_FOR_ALL` expand to `IDENTITY(X)` for all arguments? Is it also possible for arbitrary numbers of arguments?

Comment: Could you give a sample of input and what it should get preprocessed to?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use a variadic template instead of macro?

Comment: @chris `IDENTITY` is the output. I only want it to be preprocessed to another macro, nothing else.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes. In my usecase, the macro with one argument will be used to define the value of an enum. I have to do pre-processor text replacement work.

Comment: Do you want `IDENTITY_FOR_ALL(x,y,z,w)` to expand to `x,y,z,w`?

Comment: @DavidYoung no, I want it to expand to `x y z w`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as a pack expansion for variadic macros as there is for variadic templates.

You could use Boost.Preprocessor (or its methods) though.

If you don't want any commas between the elements, use

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define ID_OP(_, func, elem) func(elem)
#define APPLY_TO_ALL(func, ...)                \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(                     \
        ID_OP, func,                           \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)  \
    )

// example call:

#define SomeTransformation(x) #x // stringize the argument

APPLY_TO_ALL(SomeTransformation, 1, 2, 3) // expands to "1" "2" "3"
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d76869441d274a21).
With commas:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/enum.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define ID_OP(_, func, elem) func(elem)
#define APPLY_TO_ALL(func, ...)               \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(                        \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(                   \
        ID_OP, func,                          \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__) \
    ))

// example call:

APPLY_TO_ALL(SomeTransformation, 1, 2, 3) // expands to "1", "2", "3"
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ae2dbb641e52b83).
Check the preprocessor output with `g++ -std=c++11 -E -P file`.

Comment: Dang I need to learn to SEQ when I need access to each element. TUPLE doesn't have a FOR_EACH

Comment: @chris Yeah, SEQs are really sexy (no pun intended).

Comment: it seems like the first one (which is the one I want) doesn't work under VC2013. `identifier "BOOST_PP_IIF_0" is undefined` :(

Comment: @iFreilicht Are you sure you included all the headers appropriately? Edit: In hindsight I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @Loopunroller Found the issue. BoostPP defined its variadics macros wrong. in `config.hpp`, it not only checks `_MSC_VER`, but also `__EDG__` (whatever that is). If latter is defined, it doesn't define `BOOST_PP_VARIADICS` or `BOOST_PP_VARIADICS_MSVC`. after doing that before including the headers, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need a PP solution, you can use `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`:

```
//invoke IDENTITY_FOR_ALL_MACRO with each index and the given tuple
#define IDENTITY_FOR_ALL(...)                   \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(                            \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__),    \
        IDENTITY_FOR_ALL_MACRO,                 \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__) \
    )

//use the index to access the right element of the passed tuple
#define IDENTITY_FOR_ALL_MACRO(z, n, data) \
    IDENTITY(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(n, data))

IDENTITY_FOR_ALL(abc, 123, "woopee")
//translated to abc 123 "woopee"
```

It would be decently straightforward to turn this into a more general macro that takes a macro to invoke and the list of single arguments to pass one by one if you need to do this with several different macros and not just `IDENTITY`.

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by an arbitrary number of arguments, but if you want to invoke `IDENTITY` with two arguments at a time instead of one, you can change the bottom macro to use `BOOST_PP_MUL` and `BOOST_PP_INC` to access the "2n"th and "2n+1"th elements of the tuple, and then invoke the macro only half as many times in the `REPEAT` call.

Comment: +1 `#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Comment: By arbitrary number of arguments I mean exactly that. I've seen some specialised solutions for variadic macro unpacking that involved defining macros for every single number of arguments, so I wanted to know if there's a better solution. Apparently there is.

Comment: @iFreilicht, Ah, yeah, Boost already did that for you. `REPEAT` alone is something like 3*256 separate macros plus ones to choose the right macros to invoke.